# Cluster the tweets using important hashtags

Tags: clustering, text-mining

i extract and rank a list of the important hashtags (using td-idf ) from the twitter dataset(twitter.csv) that just includes list of tweets and now i have 9 important hashtags, now i want to use those important hashtags as nodes and cluster(preferably dendrogram) all the tweets.

explanation: 
i first came up with a character class that include all hashtags in the twitter data,then i use Corpus for text mining it, then i save them into a Term Document Matrix (a.tdm), and further i came up with the list of important hashtags.

my problem is i can not find a way to use those hashtags for clustering the whole data, i am trying the code below to cluster but it only clusters those hashtag names.

```
a.tdm.sp <- removeSparseTerms(a.tdm, sparse=0.989)
mydata.df <- as.data.frame(inspect(a.tdm.sp))
mydata.df.scale <- scale(mydata.df)
d <- dist(mydata.df.scale, method = "euclidean")
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward")
plot(fit)
groups <- cutree(fit, k=5)
rect.hclust(fit, k=5, border="red")
```

i hope i could have explained enough.

Comment: You could create an *nxp* similarity matrix where the *p's* are the important hashtags and the *n's* are all of the other hashtags, which would treat the important hashtags as *seed* input to a hierarchical clustering routine.

Comment: thank you, but how can i create a similarity matrix that use important hashtags a p and other hashtags as n, because i don't understand why there should be any similarity between important hashtags and other hashtags ?

Comment: Are you saying there's *no* association between the "important" hashtags and the others? If that's so, then what were you hoping to base an analysis on?

Comment: yes i am not looking for relationship between other hashtags and important hashtags , i want to use those important hashtags and cluster the tweets that are having those hashtags inside them

Comment: Ok...then replace the *n* hashtags with tweets.